# JavaScript: else statement inside a for..in loop is breaking my if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-in-loop

I have an if statement inside a `for in` loop that works fine, but when I add an `else` statement at the end, the code breaks - as in the variable (key in this case) from the `for..in` loop doesn't get passed to the `else` statement. Here's the code:

```
config = {'test1':2, 'test2':2, 'test3':5, 'test4':8}

  for (key in config) {
    if (isNaN(item)) {
      return item;
    }
    if (key.indexOf(baseCcy) !== -1) {
      console.log("match config");
      item = parseFloat(item).toFixed(config[key]);
      return item;
    } else {
      item = parseFloat(item).toFixed(10);
      return item;
    }
  }
```

baseCcy and item is an input from angular, from the following code: `| {{fill.price | decimalFilter:baseCcy}}` The point of this is to create a custom filter and I'm doing a for..in loop inside the filter to achieve it. So far, it's working well, but the else statement just breaks it. The point of the else statement is if none of the input from `item` matches the config array, return the item with 10 decimals.

Of note, when I console.log `key` after the for..in loop, it only shows me "test1", but when I remove else statement (with only the two if), console.log key shows me "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4".
'

Comment: The if and the else both have a return statement, so your for loop will always stop after the first item. I *think* what you want is to move the body of the else to after the loop so that it only happens if none of the items matched the if condition by the end of the loop.

Comment: Now what is your propose of using the for loop? Do you want to return all the items at last or return the item for first loop itself??

Comment: @Reddy The purpose of the for loop is to get all the property names of the array config ('test1', 'test2'). Then run an if statement to match the input (item) with the variable from for..in (key). First if will return me the item in it's default state if it's NaN, second if statement if the core part, then the else statement is if input matches nothing, return the default value + 10 decimals.

Comment: @Mjaaay check my answer and let me know if this help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just making some changes to your current logic, this must work for you.

```
config = {'test1':2, 'test2':2, 'test3':5, 'test4':8}
var newItemValue; // a new varialble
  for (key in config) {    
    if (isNaN(item)) {
      newItemValue = item
      break;  //break once you find the match
     //return item;      
    }
    else if (key.indexOf(baseCcy) !== -1) {
      console.log("match config");
      item = parseFloat(item).toFixed(config[key]);
      newItemValue = item
      break;//break once you find the match
      //return item;       
    } 
  }
  //if the loop was a failure, then do this by default.
  if(typeof newItemValue === 'undefined'){  // check if there is no value assigned to the new variable, if its not then the loop was a failure
      item = parseFloat(item).toFixed(10);
      newItemValue = item     
  }
```

Here is a link to [Working JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/axLkfggh/3/)

The output of the above logic is (when `item = 12.12345678` and `baseCcy ='test3'`)

```
12.12346
```

**EDIT:** After reading your last comment, I think this is what you want.

```
  config = {'test1':2, 'test2':2, 'test3':5, 'test4':8}

  for (key in config) {
    if (isNaN(item)) {
      return item;
    }
    if (key.indexOf(baseCcy) !== -1) {
      console.log("match config");
      item = parseFloat(item).toFixed(config[key]);
      return item;
    } 
  }
  //if the program has reached this line then the loop was a failure
  item = parseFloat(item).toFixed(10);
  return item;
```

Here no need of the new variables, another else and stuff.

Comment: I am creating a new object which is modified version of your config.

Comment: ok let me change the logic, I thought `item` was your current loop of object  property value

Comment: My bad! I didn't provide all the details because it's a messy codebase + I assumed there was an obvious newbie mistake in it. In the  future I will try to isolate the code and provide a jsfiddle, let me take a look at your help and I'll be back soon.

Comment: @Mjaaay Also the updated the fiddle, Use the new link in answer

Comment: It worked! Changing the ``else statement`` to a new ``if typeof`` was the key to fixing it. I'm not 100% sure why but I'm going to read into it. Also, since this is a custom filter in angular, I needed to add ``return newItemValue`` to the end of each if statements and remove the break, that's just how angular works I guess! Thank you Reddy! edit: i removed some of my previous comments, so people can see this comment without clicking the "see more comments" button.

Comment: @Mjaaay glad to know it helps, Also I updated my answer with new code. I think this is what you want. Till now we were battling with minimal data you provided :) so couldn't give you this code at first

Comment: Yep! I refactored it to the following and it works too. `for (key in config) {
        if (isNaN(item)) {
          return item;
        } else if (key.indexOf(baseCcy) !== -1) {
          item = parseFloat(item).toFixed(config[key]);
          return item;
        }
      }
      if (typeof item === 'string') {
        item = parseFloat(item).toFixed(2);
        return item;
      }` I think this managed to reduce the code by around 40%

Answer (score 2):

You can only return from a function !

If you want to exit a loop structure, use `break`.

Link to the relevant [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/break).

Example:

```
var conf;

for (key in config) {

    var item = config[key];

    if (isNaN(item)) {
        conf = item;
        break;
    }
    if (key.indexOf(baseCcy) !== -1) {
        console.log("match config");
        item = parseFloat(item).toFixed(config[key]);
        conf = item;
        break;
    } else {
        item = parseFloat(item).toFixed(10);
        conf = item;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, this if actually a function inside my controller.  I didn't think I needed to include the entire code, my bad.. It looks something like: ``app.filter('decimalFilter', function() {
    return function(item) {
      var baseCcy, config, key;`` etc... I stated that the code worked, just not with the else statement, and I assumed that was enough to imply that this was a function already

Comment: Please do post a Jsfiddle, so we can investigate

Comment: apologies for not coming up with a fiddle, I assumed there was an obvious newbie mistake in my if statement, but I see now that I need to provide more details. Let me look through a bit and see if I can create a fiddle